# OBJLoader not displaying anything

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, objloader

I'm trying three js with OBJ files, but it does not get rendered on the screen, can someone please  help me with this issue? is there something obvious I'm missing?

On the other hand, a geometric cube renders perfectly.

***OBJ file can be downloaded here***: https://free3d.com/pt/3d-model/tote-bag-womens-v1--846558.html

***index.js:***

```js
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls'
import { OBJLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader'
import sacola from './sacola.obj';

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
const loader = new OBJLoader();
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(5)


scene.add(axesHelper)
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
renderer.setClearColor('#000', 0)
camera.position.set(0,0,8);
controls.enableDamping = true
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


// const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
// const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
// const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
// scene.add( cube );

loader.load(sacola, (model) => {
        model.position.set(0, 0, -53);
        scene.add( model )
    },
);

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    controls.update();
}
animate()
```

***index.html:***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Apresentação 3D</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

***webpack.config.js:***

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        assetModuleFilename: 'assets/[hash][ext][query]',
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 3001,
        open: true,
        allowedHosts: 'all'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif|obj)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource'
            },
            {
                test: /\.obj$/,
                loader: 'webpack-obj-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [ 
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: './src/public/index.html', inject: true })
    ],
}
```

***Code structure:***

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

The problem was my OBJ loader inside webpack, for some reason using

```js
 {
   test: /\.obj$/,
   loader: 'webpack-obj-loader'
 }
```

made so my code did not work.

removing it solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

You have to add some lights to your scene otherwise the asset will be rendered black. Try it with something like:

```js
const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff, 0.4 );
scene.add( ambientLight );

const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
directionalLight.position.set( 100, 100, 0 );
scene.add( directionalLight );
```

Also move your camera away from the origin. The OBJ is quite big so try it with:

```js
camera.position.set(0,0,50);
```

Comment: The scene was alreadty without any black background, i made sure of that.

Comment: Also, the problem i figured it out, i'm answer it